# TypeError:- Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: reactjs

I have just started learning React. I am getting this error in localhost:3000 when I am running the server through node.js

> TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

**Index.js**

```
import React , {Compnonent} from "react";

class lottery extends Compnonent {
    render() {
        return (
            <h1>Decentralized Lottery Application</h1>
        )
    }
}

export default lottery;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo {Component} fix it.

You spelled it as  {Compnonent}

```
import React , {Component} from "react";
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for the correction.
Such a silly mistake I did

Comment: Glad, I was able to help:) Please accept the answer.